# Issue in doing SCP with AWS LightSail pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, scp, pem, amazon-lightsail

I already read no of posts and comments in stackoverflow with different ways but still i am having the following issue on the SCP with AWS LightSail pem file.

i tried to copy the files from linux (Centos) machine to the AWS LightSail (Ubuntu).

Please someone tell me what am i missing here and why this is asking for a password and if i enter it is losing connection, AWS Lightsail does not give any password except that pem file:

```
# scp -i LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem -r /home/webadmin/SOMEDOMAIN.com/html/ bitnami@13.232.191.230:/opt/bitnami/apps/newwebsite/htdocs/
The authenticity of host '13.232.191.230 (13.232.191.230)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 52:cb:2f:95:e1:77:2c:ac:50:66:89:83:15:7f:52:f4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added '13.232.191.230' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem
Enter passphrase for key 'LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem':
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Appreciate your guidance...

Answer (score 5):

### **Here is the solution and sequence of steps to follow:**

**Step1**: chmod 400 to your LightSailprivatekey which is in .pem extenstion/format.

**Step2**:Before doing the SCP from any Linux machine, Let us do the SSH first and see able to connect to the remote server as follows:
Note: This step is for verification only otherwise can go to Step4 directly.

```
 [root@previousdomainserver ~]# ssh -i LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem bitnami@13.126.197.129                                  Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1063-aws x86_64)
       ___ _ _                   _
      | _ |_) |_ _ _  __ _ _ __ (_)
      | _ \ |  _| ' \/ _` | '  \| |
      |___/_|\__|_|_|\__,_|_|_|_|_|

  *** Welcome to the Bitnami LAMP 5.6.36-0 ***
  *** Documentation:  https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/ ***
  ***                 https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/ ***
  *** Bitnami Forums: https://community.bitnami.com/ ***
Last login: Thu Aug  2 07:54:16 2018 from 78.269.59.279
bitnami@ip-172-26-15-210:~$
```

**Step3**: Exit from the ssh, Just type exit as follows:

```
bitnami@ip-172-26-15-210:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 13.126.197.129 closed.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@previousdomainserver~]#
```

**Step4**: Finally apply the scp command so that it works like a charm, transferring files is easy rather downloading to local machine and uploading again to destination server. You can see below the files are being copied to destination server

```
[root@previousdomainserver~]# scp -i LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem -r /home/webadmin/currentdomain.com/html/* bitnami@13.126.197.129:/home/bitnami/downloads/
about_us-09-08.php                                                                            100% 5749     5.6KB/s   00:00
about_us-25-04.php                                                                            100% 6291     6.1KB/s   00:00
about_us.php                                                                                  100% 5768     5.6KB/s   00:00
activate_account-24-01.php                                                                    100% 1489     1.5KB/s   00:00
activate_account.php                                                                          100% 1520     1.5KB/s   00:00 
admin-01-03.php
```

Also, to speed up the process, tar/zip the respective folder and apply scp so that it will be faster than doing file by file

Hope this helps to any other one in need...

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the file holding your private key read only.

For Linux this is very easy:

chmod 400 LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem

The number 400 means read only for the owner and no permissions for anyone else (group and other).

Comment: Hi Hanely,  Something progressed but one issue is as follows: `**
[root@beyondsquare ~]# scp -i LightsailDefaultPrivateKey-ap-south-1.pem -r /home/webadmin/somedomain.com/html bitnami@13.127.209.154:/home/bitnami/apps/newsite/htdocs/
scp: /home/bitnami/apps/newsite/htdocs//html: Permission denied**`

Comment: This error means that you are either using the wrong user name (root) or the the wrong private key or you actually do not have permissions on the remote system. I would get ssh working first and then scp.

Comment: Thanks Joh Hanley for the guidance and help, It worked like a charm. Posting as an answer to this in the main thread.

Comment: @UM1979 - Your answer will help others. Thank you.